# How can i send data from my REST WebService to my Xamarin App?

Tags: c#, api, web-services, xamarin, webservice-client

I need help with my program. I state that I'm still a beginner, so sorry if the question is trivial.

Problem: I finished developing my REST webservices using SqlConnection. My problem now is to make the data I have on my xamarin forms application (currently static) dynamic.

**Below is a part of the code where I statically declare the data:**

```
public class MockDataStore: IDataStore <Item>
    {
        List <Item> items;

        // Allow me to assign values ​​to the declared variables

        public MockDataStore ()
        {
            items = new List <Item> ();
            var mockItems = new List <Item>
            {
                
                new Item {Id = Guid.NewGuid (). ToString (), Nome_cognome = "1xxx1", Email = "xxx", Phone = 3333333333, Role = "Programmer", ActivityMattina = "Is updating the databases", ActivitiesAfternoon = "Presentation ", Number_Inside = 123},
                               new Item {Id = Guid.NewGuid (). ToString (), Nome_cognome = "2xx2", Email = "xxx", Phone = 3333333333, Role = "Programmer", ActivityMattina = "Is updating the databases", ActivitiesAfternoon = "Presentation ", Number_Inside = 123},

                new Item {Id = Guid.NewGuid (). ToString (), Nome_cognome = "3xxx3", Email = "3xxx3", Phone = 3333333333, Role = "Programmer", ActivityMattina = "Is updating the databases", ActivitiesAfternoon = "Presentation ", Number_Inside = 123},
           };
            foreach (var item in mockItems)
            {
                Items.Add (item);
            }
        }
```

Here, instead, the query I run on my webservices:

```
public List <Agenda> Rooms ()
        {
            List <Ansagenda> list = new List <Ansagenda> ();

            string queryString = "SELECT CDSISM, DESISM, TYPE, GSM, EMAIL, IP FROM [dbo]. [ANSIS00F] WHERE CDSISM = '44 'AND ANSIS00F.TIPO =' X ';";
            // string queryString = "SELECT CDSISM, DESISM, TYPE, GSM, EMAIL, IP, AGSIS, AGMAT, AGPOM, AGDAT, ORDER FROM [dbo]. [ANSIS00F] INNER JOIN [dbo]. [AGENDA] ON [CDSISM] = [AGSIS] WHERE ANSIS00F.TIPO = 'X' ORDER BY DESISM ASC, AGDAT ASC; ";

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand (queryString, connection);
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter (command);
            DataTable table = new DataTable ();

            connection.Open ();
            adapter.Fill (table);
            connection.Close ();

            foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
            {
                list.Add (new Ansagenda
                {
                    CDSISM = Convert.ToString (dr ["CDSISM"]),
                    DESISM = Convert.ToString (dr ["DESISM"]),
                    TYPE = Convert.ToString (dr ["TYPE"]),
                    GSM = Convert.ToString (dr ["GSM"]),
                    EMAIL = Convert.ToString (dr ["EMAIL"]),
                    IP = Convert.ToString (dr ["IP"]),
                });
            }
            return list;
        }
```

Comment: you Xamarin application needs to make a HTTP request to the webservice at the correct URL and then receive the data which the server sends back. Have you done that? And what do you mean by "dynamic" exactly? Are you asking how to pass a parameter to the webservice so that it can vary the response (e.g. filter the data by a specific field or something)? It's a bit unclear precisely what part of the process is causing you a problem.

Comment: Dynamic means: I want to use the data I have on my web services and view them in my application

Comment: Ok. Well then you just need to get your Xamarin code to make a HTTP request to the API server with the correct URL, and then receive the response, decode it from JSON into a suitable C# class structure and then you can use that data to populate your user interface view. Pretty sure you could research how to do those tasks online very easily - it's a very common scenario. Probably you can find end to end tutorials showing a demo of such a process entirely. You could then just adapt it for your particular dataset. Have you done any research at all so far?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the data from your server within the app you need to somehow get them. You can do that by making an HTTP request to the server. Let's start with a question: can you ask your server for the list of Agendas? Can you do that from a browser/POSTMAN?

I strongly advise you should read [this article](https://xamgirl.com/consuming-a-restful-web-service-in-xamarin-forms-using-refit-part-1/) and try doing something similar in your app. It's not that hard to do it and there are many advantages in using Refit.

Of course, you can make the request on your own but I am not sure if that makes sense when there are many libraries capable of doing so.